# YUI 3 error 'B.Lang is Undefined' yui-min.js line 7

Tags: yui, yui3

Im just started to play around with and learn YUI3 however even my very early experiments are failing.  Ive made a very simple first script however the page errors on load straight away in firebug with 'B.Lang is Undefined' yui-min.js line 7.  Anyone got any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled 2</title>
    <style>
        #container{
            width: 200px;
            height: 40px;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #ccc;   
        }
    </style>
    <script>

    YUI.use('node', function(Y){

        Y.one("#container").on('click', function(){
            alert("hello world"); 
        });
    })

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">CLICK</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `()` after YUI:

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y){

    Y.one("#container").on('click', function(){
        alert("hello world"); 
    });
});
```

You'd put a config object in there later if you want control over various aspects, like setting event callbacks, eg:

```
YUI({
    combine: true,
    insertBefore: 'insertScriptsBefore',
    onProgress: function(o) {
        //
    },
    onFailure: function(o) {
        //
    },
    onTimeout: function(o) {
        //
    }
}).use('node', function(Y){

    Y.one("#container").on('click', function(){
        alert("hello world"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: bloody hell I feel like a right pillock for not spotting that one ^^
However, many thanks for showing me the error of my ways =)

Comment: no worries, you're not alone :P ew, I just saw a missing closing bracket after the config object - my bad.

Comment: Learning YUI. thanks SubstanceD for asking this question and for Danjah keep helping us :)